# Something went wrong when authenticating the app to connect to Yammer

Tags: authentication, yammer

When I authenticate the app to connect to Yammer, if the `redirect_uri` contains the space, for example:

```
redirect_uri="http://www.example.com/test url/auth"
```

Yammer cannot redirect uri and show a wrong page. The page shows:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used %20 instead of space, and then used escape() to encode the url,like this:
redirect_uri=escape("http://www.example.com/test%20url/auth");
It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `%20` instead of  space. Maybe it helps.

Acording to [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)

One can tell that spaces are to be ignored.

```
The whitespace should be ignored when the URI is extracted.
```

So this is all I can suggest. Try `%20`

Comment: I have tried this method, but it cannot help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that the URL is correct then? If you make request manually is there an actual positive result? Sorry then, I personally have no idea what might be an issue here, though I am very interested in the cause and I'll be watching this question to learn myself then.

Comment: I am sure that the URL is accessible.

Comment: @Simer I don't know, but if you find your solution, please add your answer next to this one and accept your own answer, so that I with many others could know what is so special with Yammer. Thanks.